# Как сделать поиск по нескольким колонкам таблицы?

Tags: php, laravel

***контроллер***

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->input('q');
        $user = User::where('surname',$q)->get();
    return view('admin.pages.index', compact('user'));
}
```

> сейчас идет поиск по колонке surname по значению $q а мне нужно чтобы
>   помимо surname шел поиск еще и по name. как это можно реализовать??

Comment: `->orWhere('name', $q)`

Comment: Спасибо все работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дописать несколько условий таким образом:

`User::where('surname',$q)->orWhere('age', '>', 20)->get();`

Также можно группировать выборку:

```
User::where('surname',$q)
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('age', '<', 45)
            ->orWhere('age', '>', 20);
    })
    ->get();
```

Больше читайте в документации [на русском](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/queries) или [английском](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries) языке.